# Как при наведении на before оставлять изображение размытым?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как при наведении на лупу оставлять изображение размытым?

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image img {
    transition: filter .2s linear;
    z-index: 0;
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    transition: opacity .2s linear;
    transform: translateY(50%) translateX(50%);
    background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/483/483367.svg) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    z-index: 1;
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image img:hover {
    cursor: zoom-in;
    filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="public-image-zoom-image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/500">
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может так?

```
.parent .public-image-zoom-image:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events:none
}
```

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image img {
    transition: filter .2s linear;
    z-index: 0;
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    transition: opacity .2s linear;
    transform: translateY(50%) translateX(50%);
    background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/483/483367.svg) no-repeat center;
    -webkit-background-size: contain;
    background-size: contain;
    z-index: 1;
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image:hover::before {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events:none
}

.parent .public-image-zoom-image img:hover {
    cursor: zoom-in;
    filter: blur(4px);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="public-image-zoom-image">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/500">
  </div>

</div>
```